# Existence of Malthusian Parameter (general branching process)

Tags: continuity, stochastic-processes, laplace-transform, point-processes, branching-process

Consider a continuous time point process $\eta(t)$ representing the number of children in the interval $[0,t]$. Then $\eta(\infty)$ gives the total number of children of an individual. We define $\mu(t):= \mathbb{E}[\eta(t)]$ as the expected number of children in the interval $[0,t]$. In particular, we define $\mathcal{L}\mu(z):= \int_0^{\infty}e^{-zx} \mu(dx)$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

The Malthusian parameter is defined as the solution $\alpha$ of $\mathcal{L}\mu(\alpha)=1$.

If we assume that the Malthusian Parameter exists, then it follows $\mu(\infty)>1$. I ask myself if the converse is true. So if we have $\mu(\infty)>1$, thus their a Malthusian Parameter exsists. Therefore should be $\mathcal{L}\mu(z)$ continuous, but i am not sure if this is true.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use  the fact that $k=\log \mathcal {L}$ is a strictly convex function on $(0,\infty)$ (unless than $\mu$ is proportional to a Dirac measure.) We have $k(0)=\log \mu(\infty)$ and $k(\alpha)=0.$ If $k(0)<0$ then $\alpha$ exists and is unique. If $k(0)\geq 0$ there are $0,1,2$ solutions to the equation $k(\alpha)=0.$

Comment: Did i understand it correctly that just in a subcritical regime the malthusian parameter exist (and is unique) and in a supercritical regime their could be more (or zero) solutions?

Comment: What confuses me is that $\mathcal{L}\mu(\theta)$ is continuous for $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$, $\mathcal{L}\mu(0)=\mu(\infty)>1$ and $\mathcal{L}\mu(\infty)=0$. So their should be an $\alpha$?

Comment: Oh you are right, using the fact that $\mu$ is concentrated on $[0,\infty)$ we have $k(\infty)=-\infty.$ So your conjecture is correct!

Comment: Nb: $\mathcal{L}$ is finite on $(0,\infty)$ but not necessarily on the whole $R.$ Examples $\mu_1(dx)=1_{(0,\infty)}(x)dx$ or $\mu_2(dx)=e^{-x}\mu_1(dx).$

Comment: But in the most papers an assumption is that a Malthusian parameter exists. This implies then the supercriticality of the branching process. If my conjecture would be true than it would be enough just to assume supercriticality? And $\mathcal{L}\mu(z)$ could also be infinite on $(0,\infty)$?

Comment: With what I understand of your model $\mathcal{L}(z)<\infty$ by hypothesis. If  you consider monsters like $\mu(dx)=e^{x^2}1_{(0.\infty)}(x)dx$ the Laplace transform does not exist. To conclude, you must deal only with measures such that $\mathcal{L}(z)<\infty$  (which can be filled even for some unbounded mesures). The assumption of the existence of a Malthusian parameter seems to be equivalent to $\mathcal{L}(z)<\infty$ and the total mass $>1.$